# Is GKLocalPlayer's gamePlayerID different from the gamePlayerID other players in the GKMatch can access/see?

Tags: swift, game-center, gamekit

I'm trying to make a real-time peer-to-peer multiplayer game with GameKit/Game Center. I'm trying to store a dictionary of player IDs and scores (`[String:Int]`) to keep track of and share player scores during a game. Essentially, I want to be able to increment the score of a player locally, then send the updated scores dictionary to all the other players.

However, the `GKLocalPlayer.local.gamePlayerID` seems to be in a completely different format than any other connected `GKPlayer`, so when I try to access the `GKMatch.players` with the `gamePlayerID`, it isn't found (and yes, I'm aware that `GKMatch.players` doesn't contain the local player).

The `GKPlayer` has an 18-digit long integer, whereas the `GKLocalPlayer` has `A:_` and then a long hexadecimal number (I think it's 37 digits in decimal).

Can someone explain this difference or point to some resources that explain how I can implement this functionality correctly?

Here's a simplified example of what I'm doing:

```swift
var scores: [String:Int] // dictionary of [gamePlayerID:Score]
scores[myMatch.players.first.gamePlayerID] = 3
scores[GKLocalPlayer.local.gamePlayerID] = 5

sendScores(scores) // sends data to all players using myMatch.sendData()

/* 
   When the receiving players decode and try to access scores[gamePlayerIDOfSendingPlayer], 
   it isn't found because it's different from that player's gamePlayerID 
   in the receiving player's GKMatch.players array
*/
```